# Our git remote repository is not synchronized with local repository

Tags: java, eclipse, git, push, bitbucket

we have a problem with pushing our local stuff to a remote bitbucket repository.
we are doing `commit and push` but the changes do not appear in our remote master branch.

Here is the problem in the Git History view of eclipse:

[image]

Could somebody please explain to me the difference between `refs/remotes/origin/master` and `refs/heads/master`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience the eclipse git plugin ( in matter of fact most IDE git plugins) is not very reliable. So I would suggest you to try using git command line or some 3rd party solutions like TortoiseGit and try pushing again.

Answer (score 0):

`refs/remotes/origin/master` contains the SHA-1 of the commit that your local repository believes is the latest on your branch `master` in your remote `origin`. It is updated when you communicate with the remote.

`refs/heads/master` contains the SHA-1 of your latest commit on your local branch `master`.

See [Git references](https://git-scm.com/book/tr/v2/Git-Internals-Git-References) for more info.